# How to import script from upper-level directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I have the following hierarchy of folders and files:

```
top_level
   scripts
      s1.py
   notebooks
      nb1.ipynb
```

I need to import the functions of `s1.py` into `nb1.ipynb`. I already tried different methods but nothing worked. Please notice that I do not want to use `sys.path`.

This is what I tried last:

```
from .. import scripts/s1
```

Comment: @Max: What has to do my question with `Convert string representation of list to list`?

Comment: Accidental post lmao, my bad sorry, deleted comment for it can be confusing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995949/2031051)?

Possible example:

```
from top_level.scripts.s1 import func_name
```

Comment: Yes, I tried it. There should be a dot before `top_level`. Anyway it fails with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.top_level'; '__main__' is not a package`